# How to enforce private constructors in children of a base class

Tags: c++

I want to force children of a base class to have private constructors. Then I want those constructors to be called through a friend class which is the factory class. This is my usage pattern:

I have a class Base:

```
class Base:
    virtual double method1();
```

I want `Child` to inherit Base:

```
class Child::Base :
  public:
    Child(string s) {
       //do something
    }

    double method1() {
          return field1;
    }

  private:
     double field1;
}
```

Children of `Base` would be created by parsing a `string`. So I could have a constructor of `Base` that takes a `string`. But I can't make constructors virtual and therefore not enforce parameters.

So in order to ensure that children of `Base` can only be created from an input `string`, I want children of `Base` to be instantiated from a factory class. My problem is that nothing prevents someone from instantiating `Child` separately. Therefore, I want to enforce constructors of children of `Base` to be private and then have the factory class as a friend class.

Any ideas? Even comments on this design are welcome.

PS: To get from a string to an instance of `Child` would be different for every child.

Comment: I didn't get the root of your question clearly, if you say "I want children of Base to always have field1" why not just move field1 to Base class then?

Comment: changed the question. I was trying to abstract the question into a simple example but obviously i failed.

Comment: You can mark default constructor of Base private, thus the Child constructor will be forced to call the one you have with a string as parameter or get an error "no appropriate default constructor available (C2512)"

Comment: To get from a string to an instance of `Child` would be different for every child.I am guessing you are assuming that there is a common way to do that and we can put it in base)

Comment: You cannot control what interfaces other programmers will provide to *their* classes.

Comment: I cant. I only want to control instantiation

Comment: Generally @n.m. is right. Even if there will be a way to force the string in child constructor, how you will force the usage of this string in it then (I'll create the string param, but will not use it, just in spite)? That's why I initially said "I didn't get the root of your question clearly"

Comment: Inheritance goes quite smoothly with class factory. Use a register class method to allow new inherited classes to be instantiated by the factory.

Answer (score 2):

You can disallow creation of derived classes, not by forcing their constructors to be private, but by forcing them to be abstract. Here's a working example:

```
class A
{
    private:
        struct secret{};
        virtual void impossible(secret) = 0; // cannot override this in subclasses
                                             // because the parameter type is private

        template <class X> class AImpl : public X
        {
            void impossible(secret) {}; // a nested class can access private members
        };

        template<class X> friend X * AFactory();

    public:
        virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
    // void impossible(A::secret) {}; -- can't do that, A::secret is private!
};

template <class X>
X * AFactory()
{
    return new A::AImpl<X>;
};

int main ()
{
    // B b; -- can't do that, B is abstract!
    B* pB = AFactory<B>(); // Ok
}
```